# Как передать данные с одного компонента в другой в React?

Tags: reactjs, компоненты

У меня есть компонент `AddUser`:

```
const AddUser = props =>{
 
  let editing = false;
  let initialUsername = "";
  let initialGroups = [];
  .....
}
```

Как в  `initialGroups` получить все группы которые есть в БД ?

есть компонент который возвращает все групы :

```
const GroupList = props => {
  const[groups, setGroups] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
  retrieveGroups();
})

const retrieveGroups = () => {
  BackendService.getAllGroups()
  .then(response => {
    setGroups(response.data);
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
  });
}

return(...)
}
```

тут идет запрос в БД :

```
BackendService.getAllGroups()
  .then(response => {
    setGroups(response.data);
```

идет запрос в БД.

Как используя `GroupList`

назначить `initialGroups` равным всем группам в БД ?

Comment: Что вам мешает передавать эти данные через пропсы или через контекст?

Comment: @xydope , буду благодарен если скинете примеры похожие , а то целый день ищу.

Comment: [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)